# Possible to have multiple Authorize.net accounts on the same site?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce

I've got a site that serves several business units of a company. The company would like to be able to sell different products from each business unit. Each business unit has their own Authorize.net account and would like to process transactions using their own Authorize.net account.

So:

- Business Unit A would like to sell widget A, and process the
  transaction on Authorize.net account A.
- Business Unit B would like to sell widget B, and process the
  transaction on Authorize.net account B.
- Business Unit C would like to sell widget C, and process the
  transaction on Authorize.net account C.

For bookkeeping reasons, they can't share a single authorize.net account. The site is using WooCommerce.

I've done a fair amount of searching, and I've found plugins and methods for using multiple different gateways (e.g. Authorize.net and Stripe) but not multiple accounts for the same gateway, because keys tend to be per install.

I'm pretty sure the answer to the question is "no", but I want to make sure I'm not giving up prematurely.

Comment: This will be achievable - it should be possible to enhance the authorize.net plugin to support multiple accounts, yes, or worst case you can just clone the plugin twice, changing all the identifiers, so that WooCommerce sees them as entirely separate payment providers.

Comment: It looks like [the Authorize.net integration](https://woocommerce.com/products/authorize-net-cim/) is a paid-for plugin. I'd [contact the authors](https://www.skyverge.com/contact/) to ask about this: they can probably give you a better idea how hard it will be to modify yourself, or you might convince them to enhance it for you. (but probably only for a fee)

Comment: I've run across the same scenario... did you ever find a solution to this?